# How to configure mollie webhook url?

Tags: php, laravel, configuration, mollie

I was wondering where i should configure the mollie webhook url. I don't find any solutions in the mollie documentation. In my laravel project i already have the route setup and the controller.

```
Route::post('bestelling/webhook', 'FrontOrderController@webhook');
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

For a webhook from a third party, you may have to disable CSRF on the route. This can be done in the `VerifyCsrfToken.php` in `App\Http\Middleware`

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris